# Auto Updating an Excel Spreadsheet/Graph in One Note (In Real Time?)

Tags: excel, ms-access, onenote, vba

So here is what we are trying to do:
My boss has a bunch of monitors and wants to display our monthly metrics in real time. I've built a database in MS Access that pulls the data from a list in SharePoint and then that linked table is in turn linked to an Excel Spreadsheet. The datasheet is then setup on a second sheet that has a 3-D pivot table showing the data in graph form. I then have added this graph to One Note for display. The problem is One Note won't update the Excel Spreadsheet. Is there a way to have one note update the spreadsheet/Graph in real time or update it periodically (say every hour?) 
I've been looking around via Google search and found "Some" info but nothing directly to what I'm looking for or explaining how to do it.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!!!
-D

Comment: I know OneNote has lots of limitations.  One workaround is to have VBA open OneNote and import an image from a range in Excel.  The VBA macro would have a timer, and after X duration, you can close (no save) the OneNote note, then open a new note and import the Excel range.  This is the immediate workaround that comes to mind.

Comment: So I would put the VBA macro in Excel or would I need to do this as batch file? I'm just trying to figure out how to make that work so it would run all day long and where to piggy back this code from.